# How to get the type and the size of the type from T?

Tags: scala, types, type-conversion, arrays

How can I get the type and the size of the type from T?
For example, when I'm trying to convert Integer or Long to ByteArray using generics in Scala, how can I get the type information from T?

```
def dataToByteArray[T](x: T) = {
  if T is IntType
    ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(x).array()
  else if T is LongType
    ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putLong(x).array()
  else
    raise an error
}
```

I may use polymorphic functions, but I'm curious how scala can give the type info.

```
def dataToByteArray(x: Int) = {
  ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(x).array()
}
def dataToByteArray(x: Long) = {
  ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putLong(x).array()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, but it is not that straightforward as in C/C++ -- in order to get estimate size of object of type T you have to traverse object's graph. There are some libraries for this, e.g. [jamm](https://github.com/jbellis/jamm).

Note, that usage of such libraries is extremely uncommon and very likely means that you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had hit to an idea bellow!

```
def dataToByteArray[T](x: T) = {
  x match {
   case i: Int => ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(x).array()
   case l: Long => ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putLong(x).array()
   case _ => throw new Exception("Runtime exception")
  }
}
```